# Is any API available for getting name of Instance from Instance ID in Google cloud platform

Tags: google-api-explorer

I am trying to get Instance name of Google cloud platform from Instance id in using REST API

I found some REST API but I am not able to execute it

http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/

from webpage
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata

Anyone help me to get these Information ??????

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to get the best help, you need to show what you've done so far and tell us why it isn't working. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Using API:-

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList?authuser=2

I am getting all the details of an instance.